# How to get scope attributes from a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive which consists in a form containing an input box and a button(http://plnkr.co/edit/eQrsdqA2jh08dB96QIcj?p=preview). I would like to know if there is any way I can get the content of the input box and if the form is valid from the page controller (Ctrl2), in order to put a button on the first page whose abilitation will be based on the validity of that form, like this:

```
<button ng-disabled="isDirectiveInvalid">Btn</button>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: move the isvalid function to link function

Comment: And then how can I reference it?

Comment: why dont your put just simple line in button text  "<button ng-click='isValid()' ng-disabled='form1.input1.$invalid'>VALID?</button>" it will automatically disable untill form is valid

Comment: It works! How can I get the input value instead?

Comment: you can get input value using scope.input1model